# How to do GRUB editing?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, grub2

How to do grub editing in ubuntu version 11.04 and 11.10? What is the purpose of grub editing? If anyone knows the solution please answer it..

Comment: Grub settings are in this folder /etc/grub.d now

Answer (score 1):

Grub is the bootloader - so the purpose of editing it is to change parameters during boot.

The files you can edit are /etc/default/grub and the scripts in /etc/grub.d.

Changing the grub.cfg in /boot/grub is not recommended as any changes you make manually will be overwritten the next time an update to grub is called.

If there is a specific reason that you want to edit the file please update your question.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Answer (score 0):

GRUB:= GRand Unified Boot-loader

It is a common boot loader that can boot the system, weather Linux or windows or others
Grub Editing= play with the boot configuration or customize the boot configurations.

How to edit : as said in forestpiskie's post you can manually edit those files.. or use a GUI for that...

Grub customizer is a good one ( look :[Grub Customizer installation](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/grub-customizer-2-2-released-and-installation-instructions-included.html))
Startup manager is also fine (check : [community website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager) )

BUT IF YOU MANAGE TO MESS UP WITH BOOT, You can't boot into the system... don't worry a lot of methods are there to fix the boot loader.....

The recommended one is Boot Repair....[Boot repair installation](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/boot-repair-simple-tool-to-repair-frequent-boot-problems.html) it can fix the problem even if the boot loader is deleted or corrupted...... Also keep the copy of boot repairer disk (check:[Boot-repair disk Source forge page](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)) before you attempt some thing that may corrupt the loader...

If you wanted to customize the GRUB too badly... read this [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html)

If you want to theme grub your own reading the book listed in this post may help you :[grub guide by Towheed Mohammed](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1534689)

All the best with grub editing and customizing... if for info hope that this provides necessary information.. if not ask :)